# Short to Int typecasting doesn't work why?

Tags: c, casting, int, short

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
short vShort=3;
int *iInt=(int *)&vShort ;
printf("Value of short: %d\n",vShort);
printf("Value iof short: %d\n",*iInt);
}
```

---

I wrote this code but this variable is printing valus as below.
Sizeof Int-4
Sizeof Short - 2

It is also not working when I do `"int*iInt=&vShort ;"` it gives same output.

**output:**

Value of short: 3
Value iof short: 196608

Comment: that one line is wrong on so many levels...

Comment: Didn't your compiler give any warnings about this code?  If so, you'd be wise to heed them in the future.

Comment: Honestly, I can't even tell what you are *trying* to accomplish here.

Comment: I am surprised this compiled. Could you describe what you are trying to do?

Comment: An `int *` should point to an `int`. Casting does not cause magic to occur.

Answer (score 6):

Here,

```
 int *iInt=(int)&vShort
```

You're casting the address of a variable to `int` (which is undefined behaviour, or at the very least implementation defined because an integer may not be big enough to hold the pointer's value, only `uintptr_t` is).

If you want to "cast" a `short` to an `int`, just assign it, integer promotion will take care of everything:

```
short s = 3; // note that this line already technically casts the integer literal 3 to type short
int i = s;
```

If you want a pointer to an `int` value, you'll need to either create a local variable and take its address, or allocate memory for it with `malloc`:

```
short s = 3;
int i; // if you add "= s" here you can drop the last line
int* iptr = &i;
*iptr = s;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this type of code was already present in our system where to remove warning developer typecasted short to int. Thats why i posted this question whats wrong with this code.